# Log4j No appenders could be found for logger

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm going to use two different log files in an application. the Log4j config file is this:

```
log4j.rootLogger= false

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File= D\:\\default.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


log4j.appender.instLog = org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.instLog.File= D\:\\install.log
log4j.appender.instLog.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.instLog.Append=true
log4j.appender.instLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.instLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


log4j.appender.updateLog = org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.updateLog.File= D\:\\update.log
log4j.appender.updateLog.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.updateLog.Append=true
log4j.appender.updateLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.updateLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

and the java code is this:

```
public class AppTest {
    private static Logger update = Logger.getLogger("update.log");
    private static Logger install = Logger.getLogger("install.log");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        update.info("Update");
        install.info("Install");

    }
}
```

but in runtime I got this:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (update.log).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Where is wrong?

Comment: Paste your whole log4j.xml file.

Comment: @almasshaikh I just put all contents of log4j.properteise

Answer (score 0):

update.log is the name of the appender not the logger.  You must attach the appender you have defined to some loggers.

Answer (score 0):

In your log4j.properties, you need to make use of category like below:

```
log4j.category.updateLogger=TRACE, debugLog
log4j.additivity.updateLogger=false

log4j.category.installLogger=DEBUG, reportsLog
log4j.additivity.installLogger=false
```

And in your java code, you should be using something like:

```
private static Logger update = Logger.getLogger("updateLogger");
private static Logger install = Logger.getLogger("installLogger");
```